# Small errors when baking displacement maps

Tags: image, texture-baking

I am baking a simple displacement from several Bezier curves. The curves are beveled and set to full. Whenever I bake the displacement map, I get several small errors. Here is the baked `.exr` applied via a displace modifier to a heavily subdivided plane. Several of the baking errors are circled in the image below.
[image: displacement map on a plane with errors]

What is the cause of the errors? What can I do to get rid of them during the baking process? Because I can not edit the image externally with out compression artifacts.

The [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33361), just open and press bake.

Comment: Can you give us the .blend with the baking setup to look at? Nothing can be done to help otherwise..only guesses.

Comment: You might also want to look at the .exr file itself. Maybe that will tell you what happened.

Comment: This is ANOTHER dead pasteall link. You should use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - those links will never expire after a certain time limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a baking bug to me.

Investigation shows the artifacts are already present in the .exr and the displace works as intended. I just subdivided a plane to 16.78M polys for 4096 texture and it showed the same result as you posted.

Artifacts in .exr:

[image]

Then I tried converting the curves into mesh, different curves resolutions and smoothings, normalized/unnormalized bakes but I always got black pixels at different random spots.

When I plug the raw bake into compositing nodes and inspect it it has artifacts, so it is not the exr.

The only solution that worked for me are smooth modifiers after the displacement, which is not really a solution.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know it was not specific to something on my machine. I too have tried many different settings, file types, etc. but still get the one pixel errors.

Comment: Can you give me your system specs (OS bit memory and gx card)? I want to add them to the bug report I'm filing.

Comment: Sure, it was baked on Win7 64bit, i7-4770K, 16GB ram, GTX780

Answer (score 1):

This might be of use for you :)

[How can I get rid of the black dots or black pixels in a float 32-bit EXR baked displacement map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108781/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-black-dots-or-black-pixels-in-a-float-32-bit-exr-baked)

Open the .EXR image into Blender's compositor and use these settings:

[image]

After that, save the image as OpenEXR again.

Comment: Indeed. that is a good work around.