# Normal bake randomly doesn't bake some faces

Tags: normals, texture-baking

I'm having an issue with normal map baking from a hi poly to lo poly object where occasionally, and seemingly at random, certain faces of my object don't have anything rendered to the Normal image.

If I click the bake button again, without changing anything, it will rebake and a different face will be missing from the image. I have my normal map now just from pure luck clicking bake 10 or so times until it happened to bake each face.

Why is this happening? It seems weird that it's at random...

Comment: did you ever encounter any errors like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18639/2217)?

Comment: This is not necessarily a bug. Some faces of the object could be assigned a different material (see https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-is-only-baking-to-certain-parts-of-mesh/487863/2 ). Also, with Cycles Render in 2.79, I had to turn off "Selected to active," turn on "Use nodes" for the material, and assign the image to the object in the Cycles Material. However, with Blender Render, I had to turn "Selected to active" on, even if I assigned the image to a new texture in a non-cycles material on all faces--I'm not sure why.