# How can I get rid of the black dots or black pixels in a float 32-bit EXR baked displacement map?

Tags: texture-baking, .exr

When I bake a 32-bit displacement map, it has these annoying black dots or black pixels in it:

[image: example of the black specks]

How do I get rid of these?

Comment: But...why does that happen?

Comment: nneonneo - I sure would like to know, too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Blender, use compositor's despeckle node to get rid of those. The threshold setting is very important, this should do:

[image]

Then save the image as OpenEXR.

[image]